# How to remove records having none result from a pandas series map function directly within Lambda

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

ser=pd.Series(['Apple','Mango','Cherry','Orange'])

vowels='AEIOUaeiou'

def vowel_check(ser):
    count=0
    for x in ser:
        if x in vowels:
            count+=1
            if count==2:
                return ser
ser=ser.map(lambda x: vowel_check(x))

ser
```

Output:

```
0     Apple
1     Mango
2      None
3    Orange
dtype: object
```

Expected:

```
0     Apple
1     Mango
3    Orange
```

I'm able to remove the None records ser.dropna() but can we filter them directly in lambda function ?

Thanks

Comment: can you try with : `ser[ser.str.count('|'.join(list(vowels))).ge(2)]`

Comment: No because the `lambda` is used with `Series.map`, which by definition returns a Series with **the same index as the caller**. You can certainly chain them together or combine a `map` with some slicing, but map cannot drop rows by itself.

Comment: Thanks @ALollz , for the very detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks @anky_91 for your time in answering.